# Wordpress - Get full-width content to wrap around sidebar

Tags: css, wordpress

Here's a link to the page I'm working on: http://www.noticeeverything.com/news

As you can see, the main content is fixed-width and floated left and the sidebar is fixed-width and floated right. This is the default. I messed around with it for a couple hours, but I couldn't find a way to wrap the content around the sidebar when I set the content width to 100%.

Any Wordpress experts out there? I just started learning this a couple days ago.

Comment: Also, share you code with everyone, then we can look at it :)

Answer (score 3):

This is not really the place to ask this because it is not really about code. Try asking it in other places, you might be able to find better answers. Good luck!

Comment: I am going to look for something. But for the mean time, try googling it :)

Comment: Alright, look at this: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/wrap-text-around-sidebar

Comment: The only way this could be accomplished without code is if WP Admin included some functionality for this, which I don't believe it does. I'm looking for a way to do this with CSS, or even by maybe putting the `get_sidebar()` tag elsewhere in the file system.

Comment: Well, did you try googling it?

Comment: Yep. And I've seen that page. And I've tried putting the sidebar action call inside the main content `div`. Apparently I transgressed some standard with this question.

Comment: I might agree if I knew what the standard was and how I'd transgressed it.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by placing the `get_sidebar()` tag not within `div.primary`, the container which holds ALL the posts (the place which to me seemed the most intuitive), but inside the container which holds only the FIRST post, `article` or `.entry-content`. The only issue I'm running into is that if you place the tag before the post header the content won't wrap, and if you place it after the header, the content wraps until the screen width drops below around 700px.

I imagine that's due to CSS in the parent theme. If I can't fix it with CSS I'll just set it to `display: none` at 700px and show/hide it with JS/jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `padding` `left` and `right` to zero. Don't forget to put `important`.
Your code should look like:

```
.container{
    padding-left: 0px !important;
    padding-right: 0px !important;
}
```